# Do not have access to second hard drive

Tags: server, permissions, mount, hard-drive

So I recently updated my Ubuntu server to the version 22.04.2. I have not have had this issue in the past. I am also a Linux newbie so I am having a hard time figuring this out.

But It seems like applications do not have permissions to the 2nd drive /dev/sdb2 is the path to the directory. I have in the server. If I tried to torrent to that drive I get permission denied by transmission and Plex says my files are unavailable and my drive needs to be mounted. It is mounted.

I have not had this problem until I upgraded to the latest version of Ubuntu. Anything you guys have to offer will help a ton. Thanks!

Comment: "*the latest version*" is vague --and often incorrect-- so please be precise and use the version numbers or names. Also please show us exact, complete error messages, and clearly show us the steps to reproduce those errors.

Comment: How are you mounting the drive / assigning the mount, are you using fstab or a mount command and if so what does it look like?  Is it mounting correctly?  What are the unix file permissions of the root of the mount when mounted?

Comment: It seems that I am using ver 22.04.2 LTS. I am mounting it through the gui. I am getting errors from transmission such as permission denied or from plex please check if your drive is mounted.

Comment: Could you please include some info about the folder you're writing to? Like `stat /path/to/folder`. It's most likely a permission issue.

Comment: yeah the path is /dev/sdb2